# Service injection in Startup

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, httpclient, asp.net5

How to make sure a service is injected with a  value from AppSettings, and with a HttpClient (that is made with the IHttpClientFactory)?

Here is a part of my ConfigureServices in Startup:

```
 int.TryParse(Configuration["AppSettings:soapTimeoutSeconds"], out int seconds);
 services.AddHttpClient<SoapService>();
 services.AddScoped<SoapService>();
```

This is how I construct my service:

```
Class SoapService
{
   public SoapService(HttpClient httpClient, int seconds)
   {
       this.HttpClient = httpClient;
       this.seconds= seconds;
   }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to configure timeout for `HttpClient` - there is an `AddHttpClient` [overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.httpclientfactoryservicecollectionextensions.addhttpclient?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0#Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_HttpClientFactoryServiceCollectionExtensions_AddHttpClient__1_Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_IServiceCollection_System_Action_System_Net_Http_HttpClient__) accepting configuring action:

```cs
services.AddHttpClient<SoapService>(client => client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(seconds));
```

Otherwise I would recommend you to create an class to contain this setting and register/resolve it.

Comment: Seems like a good solution, but when I use the HttpClient object in the service, it do not have the correct Timeout number. Hm, but I will keep digging why.